# ¿Cómo puedo generar un PDF con Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una App con Xamarin.forms y me estoy trabando cuando quiero generar un archivo PDF.

Necesito que al apretar un botón, se genere un PDF con ciertos datos que voy a pedir que ingrese por pantalla el usuario.

El problema que tengo es que he probado muchas librerías que encontré en internet y no he podido conseguir que me funcionaran.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con este problema? ¿Pueden pasarme algún ejemplo de como usar correctamente la librería utilizada?

Gracias de antemano!

---

[EDIT]

Dejo aquí el código para que vean como estoy armando el pdf...

```
        string filename = Configuraciones.PathApp + "/HolaMundo";
        var archivo = Path.Combine(filename, "Prueba.pdf");

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(archivo);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        Stream str = GenerateStreamFromString(filename);

        PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
        PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
        PdfStandardFont helvetica = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.Helvetica, 24);
        PdfBrush brush = new PdfBrush();
        page.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", helvetica, brush, 100, 100);
        document.Save(str);
```

Comment: Hola Matias, y que ha intentado puede mostrar el código que lleva realizado hasta el momento?

Comment: Y qué librerías has probado?

Comment: @Luis Las ultimas que recuerdo haber probado fueron PDFSharp, iTextSharp para PCL y la ultima que probé fue xfinium (la misma en la que dejo en el edit)